# Custom loss function in keras? Correntropy. Math/implementation issues

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, math, keras

Im working with a paper where it implements an autoencoder with a custom loss function to work with vibration signals.

Im having trouble implementing it on keras. They implement **"Maximum Correntropy"** as the loss function to avoid issues with background noise on a signal.

This is the description:

*Gaussian kernel is the most popular Mercer kernel in correntropy, which is defined as*
[image]

*where r is the kernel size. Then, the new autoencoder loss function can be designed by maximizing the following function:*
[image]

Since i never implemented a custom loss function im having issues with the math in python. The kernel is used on the loss function that i need to implement.
This is what i have:

[dataset.npz](https://github.com/biswajitsahoo1111/cbm_codes_open/blob/master/notebooks/data/CWRU_48k_load_1_CNN_data.npz)

```py
file = np.load('./data/CWRU_48k_load_1_CNN_data.npz')  # Numpy Array 

data = file['data'].reshape(len(file['data']), 1024)
labels = file['labels']
category_labels = np.unique(labels)
labels = pd.Categorical(labels, categories = category_labels).codes

train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = int(data.shape[0]*0.2), random_state = 100, stratify = labels)

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

# Data shape. Sample Len: 1024. Outputs/Classifications: 10
print(train_data.shape, train_labels.shape, test_data.shape, test_labels.shape)
#(3680, 1024) (3680, 10) (920, 1024) (920, 10)

act_func = 'relu'
out_func = 'softmax'
k_inic = 'glorot_uniform'  

def create_model(shape=[512, 100], loss_func='mse'):
    model = Sequential()

    for shape_size in shape:
        model.add(Dense(shape_size, activation=act_func, kernel_initializer=k_inic))

    model.add(Dense(10, activation=out_func, kernel_initializer=k_inic))
    model.compile(loss=loss_func, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.build(input_shape=(None, 1024))

    return model

BATCH_SIZE = 45
EPOCHS = 200
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.05

# Design Mercer Kernel
def kernel(x, sigma=1):
    return (1/(K.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))*K.exp((-(x*x)/(2*sigma*sigma)))

# Use Mercer Kernel on Maximum Correntropy for loss function
def correntropy(y_true, y_pred):
    sum_score = 0.0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        sum_score = kernel(y_true[i] - y_pred[i])
    sum_score = sum_score/len(y_true)
    return -sum_score

# Create AutoEncoder model with my custom loss function
model = create_model(shape=[512, 100], loss_func=correntropy)
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs = EPOCHS, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, validation_data=(test_data, test_labels), 
                        callbacks = callbacks.callbacks, verbose = 0)

res = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, verbose = 0)[1]
```

But i have this error:

```sh
AttributeError: in user code:

    /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /tmp/ipykernel_95935/2003563015.py:26 correntropy  *
        sum_score = kernel(y_true[i] - y_pred[i])
    /tmp/ipykernel_95935/2239884018.py:20 kernel  *
        return (1/(K.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))*K.exp((-(x*x)/(2*sigma*sigma)))
    /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py:2539 sqrt
        zero = _constant_to_tensor(0., x.dtype.base_dtype)

    AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

The error seems to be on the `kernel`, but how do i fix to work with tensors?

```
print(y_true)
print(y_pred)
>> Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)
>> Tensor("sequential_161/dense_491/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Can you try wrapping the floats as numpy scalars? E.g. `K.sqrt(np.float32(2*np.pi))`? That should give these constants a `dtype` and shut the error up. Aside from that, if you are working with `keras` (the standalone installation) and not `tf.keras` (submodule that comes with installing Tensorflow), I woud recommend rather using the latter and replacing low-level ops with their Tensorflow equivalents, e.g. using `tf.sqrt` instead. But note that you _cannot_ mix standalone `keras` with `tensorflow` -- only `tf.keras`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 main things I notice in your code:

1. You are combining math functions from different packages (K, np). Stick to to native tensorflow functions as much as possible (e.g. tf.math.reduce_sum). There's lots of stuff. Check the [documentation for an overview](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/)
2. Custom loss functions should be converted into tensorflow graph-compatible functions, which is as easy as putting the `tf.function` decorator in front of it. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function)
3. Loops usually don't do well. Vectorise your functions as much as possible.

All together I reckon something like this should work (didn't test it):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_2pi = tf.constant(tf.sqrt(2*np.pi), dtype=tf.float32)

@tf.function
def kernel(x, sigma=1):
    return (1 / (tf_2pi * sigma)) * tf.exp((-(x * x) / (2 * sigma * sigma)))


@tf.function
def correntropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return -tf.math.reduce_mean(kernel(y_true - y_pred))
```